# How to use the variable __DEV__ in ReactJs like in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my react-native projects I use the global variable `__DEV__` and I would like to use something similar in my Typescript reactJs project but when I try to use it I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `process` has an attribute that allow to achieve this:

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```